# Using multiple arguments with custom tab completion

Tags: autocompletion

I have a command line tool that requires three parameters in the form of:

```
command input1 input2
```

I'm trying to write a custom complete function that handles completion for different arguments... well, differently.

Determining which argument I'm on and returning a different set of completion options isn't hard; I've got that figured out:

```
function! CustomCompletion(argLead, line, pos)
   let argList = split(a:line)
   if     len(argList) == 1
      " Do completion for arg 1 (the command)
   elseif len(argList) == 2
      " Do completion for arg 2
   elseif len(argList) == 3
      " Do completion for arg 3
   endif
endfunction
```

My problem is with the "argLead" variable. [`:h command-completion-custom`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command-completion-custom) says this:

> ArgLead: the leading portion of the argument currently being
>   completed on.

[Places Iv'e researched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937984/is-there-a-way-to-make-use-of-two-custom-complete-functions-in-vim-script) seem to imply that this variable contains the current white-space separated argument that the cursor is on. However whenever I use it, the variable contains the whole command line (spaces and all). Additionally when I press tab after say, the second argument, the tab completion tries to match the whole command line instead just the current argument.

Is there some way to tell the completion function to parse args based on white-space?

Oh, and I'm calling this function in the thrid paramater of input() if that makes any difference.

```
let user = input("Enter a command\n", "", "custom,CustomCompletion")
```

Thanks

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the problem comes from the `input()` function, not the completion function. When you write a completion function for a command, you can tell the latter that it must wait for several arguments thanks to the attribute `-nargs=+`. I don't think there's something equivalent for `input()` which is probably why it will always send the whole command line as an argument to the completion function. Maybe you could make 3 distinct calls to `input()`: http://vpaste.net/FovYz and build `user` afterwards.

Comment: Otherwise, your completion function would have several problems to solve. If `input()` can only complete the whole command line, your completion function will have to return not just the completion of an argument, but the whole command. Besides, at the moment, your completion function chooses which candidates to return based on the number of "words" on the line (`if len(argList) == 1`), but to work properly I think it should also take into account the position of the cursor. That problem seems to be solved in the link you gave though.

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific. Especially regarding how you want to use this. Based on the first part of the question, I get the impression that you are defining a command, e.g. with `command -complete ...`. Later, I understand this is not the case, and it gets confusing. Can you explain how the tool should be used when it works as expected?

Comment: Sorry, I try not to bore people with details that I don't think help solve the problem. The context is that I'm designing a "package manager" within vim for multiple directory projects. This tool will make it easier for me to search within a predefined set of directories easily (And don't tell me there's a plugin for it. I wanted to write it myself :).

This issue comes up in the tool to edit the packages. Once the tool is activated via a user command, the user is then prompted (via an input() ) for a command. They can also supply optional arguments to the command. i.e. `add Foo .`

Comment: This will add the current directory to package Foo. Anyway I have a workaround (posted below). If you have a better answer feel free to post it, but I can work with what I've got for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that saginaw is correct. The problem resides in the fact that `input()` handles completion differently than the `command!` function. I don't think that the author of the `input()` function gave much thought to custom completion and only added partial support for it. As saginaw mentions, the `intput()` function has no `-nargs` parameter like `command!`. As a result the `ArgLead` parameter will always be the whole command line, and consequently the match will always be performed against the whole command line.

## Workaround:

One possible solution is to prepend the previously typed arguments for completion. That way when the match is performed it will at least be able to see that the user input matches the predefined completions. I accomplished this in this way:

```
function! CustomCompletion(argLead, line, pos)
   let argList = split(a:line)
   let returnString = ""
   if     len(argList) == 1
      " This is the first argument so nothing special here

   elseif len(argList) == 2
      " Second argument needs to add first argument to completion
      for item in myCompletionList
         let returnString .= argList[0] . " " . item . "\n"
      endfor
      return returnString

   endif
endfunction
```

This does work reasonably well. The drawback is that if you have `windmenu` set, the suggestions include the whole command line which is kind of annoying and hard to see if you have a lot of items.

Example:
[image: Whole command line match]

At present I see no other alternatives, so this will have to do.

As far as the other issue that saginaw mentioned, that is solved (as he stated) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937984/is-there-a-way-to-make-use-of-two-custom-complete-functions-in-vim-script). However, I didn't include it in the code since I didn't think it was relevant to the current problem and would just clutter the example.